# CreateProcess returns handle different than launched Chrome.exe

Tags: google-chrome, winapi, createprocess

I am using CreateProcess and giving Chrome.exe as the argument.

I am getting the handle of the process I created using `PROCESS_INFORMATION` which internally has `hProcess`

When I print the PID using `GetProcessId(handle)` I am getting a different PID than the ones showing in the task manager.

I have tried setting callback function to trigger after Chrome.exe exists, but it triggers anyway. This is expected (not desired) since Chrome.exe PID is different.

It seems like when I use CreateProcess on Chrome.exe, chrome takes liberty to start its own new process and render all my control useless.

I have tried using it with FireFox.exe and it worked well, I got the handle it pointed to the correct process.

Is it not possible to get handles to Chrome processes I spawn?

Comment: Chrome, like all modern browsers, uses multiple processes to provide isolation against browser plugin crashes. That's just how browsers work today. We can't advise how you should solve your problem because we don't what it is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I want to get handle to the Chrome process I am spawning. I am getting the handle to Firefox processes with no issues...

Comment: "I want to get handle to the Chrome process I am spawning." That's what you get back from CreateProcess. And it's of no use to you. So no, you don't want the process handle that you spawn.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That is incorrect. CreateProcess returns a number indicating the success or failure of the creation. The handle, however, is of use to me because I want to wait on it to close before proceeding with certain parts in my code. I can do that with the handle to the correct process. As I said, IT WORKED with Firefox. So you're not solving any problems telling me that I don't have a problem when I clearly do. It works with Firefox, it doesn't with Chrome. Isn't that hard to understand.

Comment: CreateProcess returns multiple things. Including two handles via an out parameter. And it is returning the handle to the process you spawn. It's just not the process handle that you actually need due to the multiple process design. The reason that chrome and Firefox behave differently is simple to understand. They are different programs. Different versions of Firefox and chrome may behave differently still. It's a constantly evolving and changing scene.

Comment: Now, what you can surely do is obtain ids and handles for the processes spawned by the Chrome process that you create. If you know the architecture and design of each version of chrome that you support this is quite possible.

Comment: @Everyone what problem are you _actually_ trying to resolve? Is this an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: I have this same issue. When there's an existing chrome, the newly launched process passes the request to the existing chrome and then exits.  I would really like to keep track of the currently launched version, and have it NOT exit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Chrome process you are spawning with `CreateProcess()` is, in turn, spawning its own child process(es) and then terminating itself.  Your Firefox is not doing that, at least not initially (Firefox does use child processes for  browser tabs - most modern browsers do, for security and stability).

So, the Chrome PID/handle you get from `CreateProcess()`, albeit valid, is short-lived and clearly useless for your needs.

But, all is not lost. You can get notified about the child PID(s) that Chrome itself spawns. Add your spawned Chrome process to a [job object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/job-objects), then use [`SetInformationJobObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/jobapi2/nf-jobapi2-setinformationjobobject) to assign that job to an [I/O completion port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/i-o-completion-ports), then use [`GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986(v=vs.85).aspx) to receive events from the job, in particular `JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NEW_PROCESS` whenever a new process is created in the job, and `JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ACTIVE_PROCESS_ZERO` when all processes in the job have ended.  See [How do I wait until all processes in a job have exited?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130405-00/?p=4743) for more details.