# How to get the process ID when starting Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: c++, winapi, pid, createprocess

The task of getting the PID of the process that I'm starting, `CreateProcess()` `ProcessInformation.dwProcessId` does a great job of this, but in my case, the process that I start opens the child processes and then closes, and I need to get all the PIDs that creates the process I am opening.

I found this code, it receives the child PIDs but they do not match the final Firefox window, what am I doing wrong

Source:
[CreateProcess returns handle different than launched Chrome.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54644803/createprocess-returns-handle-different-than-launched-chrome-exe)

**Update 1**
After Drake Wu - MSFT comment, I used the following code

```
int test(const wchar_t* programPath) {
    HANDLE Job = CreateJobObject(nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!Job) {
        std::cout << "CreateJobObject, error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    HANDLE IOPort = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nullptr, 0, 1);
    if (!IOPort) {
        std::cout << "CreateIoCompletionPort, error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    JOBOBJECT_ASSOCIATE_COMPLETION_PORT Port;
    Port.CompletionKey = Job;
    Port.CompletionPort = IOPort;
    if (!SetInformationJobObject(Job,
        JobObjectAssociateCompletionPortInformation,
        &Port, sizeof(Port))) {
        std::cout << "SetInformation, error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInformation;
    STARTUPINFOW StartupInfo = { sizeof(StartupInfo) };
    LPWSTR szCmdline = const_cast<LPWSTR>(programPath);

    if (!CreateProcessW(
        programPath,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        FALSE,
        CREATE_SUSPENDED,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        &StartupInfo,
        &ProcessInformation))
    {
        std::cout << "CreateProcess, error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "PID: " << ProcessInformation.dwProcessId << std::endl;
    if (!AssignProcessToJobObject(Job, ProcessInformation.hProcess)) {
        std::cout << "Assign, error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    ResumeThread(ProcessInformation.hThread);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hThread);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hProcess);

    DWORD CompletionCode;
    ULONG_PTR CompletionKey;
    LPOVERLAPPED Overlapped;
    while (GetQueuedCompletionStatus(IOPort, &CompletionCode, &CompletionKey, &Overlapped, INFINITE))
    {
        switch (CompletionCode)
        {
        case JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NEW_PROCESS:
            std::cout << "New PID: " << (int)Overlapped << std::endl;
            break;
        case JOB_OBJECT_MSG_EXIT_PROCESS:
            std::cout << "Exit PID: " << (int)Overlapped << std::endl;
            break;
        case JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ACTIVE_PROCESS_ZERO:
            std::cout << "JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ACTIVE_PROCESS_ZERO" << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        if (CompletionCode == JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ACTIVE_PROCESS_ZERO)
            break;
    }
    std::cout << "All done" << std::endl;
}
```

and I got the following results:

[standart Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sHxi.png)

`test(L"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");`

[portable edition Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy7GB.png)

`test(L"D:\\FirefoxPortable\\FirefoxPortable.exe");`

As before, PIDs are incorrectly returned. In the case of the portable version, the process hangs on the while loop, in the case of the standard version of firefox, `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` returns `JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ACTIVE_PROCESS_ZERO`. Why am I getting the wrong result?

**Update 2**

I ran Visual Studio as an administrator and, but on standard startup everything displays correctly

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested that the process of Firefox is not new and exit in order(the pid obtained by `CreateProcess` will exit), and your code will not receive the new Firefox process if there is any new process created later.

You could use `swtich-case` statement, the following sample work for me:

```
int openProgram(const wchar_t* programPath) {
    HANDLE Job = CreateJobObject(nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!Job) {
        std::cout << "CreateJobObject, error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    HANDLE IOPort = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nullptr, 0, 1);
    if (!IOPort) {
        std::cout << "CreateIoCompletionPort, error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    JOBOBJECT_ASSOCIATE_COMPLETION_PORT Port;
    Port.CompletionKey = Job;
    Port.CompletionPort = IOPort;
    if (!SetInformationJobObject(Job,
        JobObjectAssociateCompletionPortInformation,
        &Port, sizeof(Port))) {
        std::cout << "SetInformation, error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInformation;
    STARTUPINFO StartupInfo = { sizeof(StartupInfo) };
    LPTSTR szCmdline = _tcsdup(programPath);
    if (!CreateProcessW(
        nullptr,
        szCmdline,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        FALSE,
        CREATE_SUSPENDED,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        &StartupInfo,
        &ProcessInformation))
    {
        std::cout << "CreateProcess, error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "PID: " << ProcessInformation.dwProcessId << std::endl;
    if (!AssignProcessToJobObject(Job, ProcessInformation.hProcess)) {
        std::cout << "Assign, error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    ResumeThread(ProcessInformation.hThread);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hThread);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hProcess);

    DWORD CompletionCode;
    ULONG_PTR CompletionKey;
    LPOVERLAPPED Overlapped;
    while (GetQueuedCompletionStatus(IOPort, &CompletionCode, &CompletionKey, &Overlapped, INFINITE))
    {
        switch (CompletionCode)
        {
        case JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NEW_PROCESS:
            std::cout << "New PID: " << (int)Overlapped << std::endl;
            break;
        case JOB_OBJECT_MSG_EXIT_PROCESS:
            std::cout << "Exit PID: " << (int)Overlapped << std::endl;
            break;
        case JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ACTIVE_PROCESS_ZERO:
            std::cout << "JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ACTIVE_PROCESS_ZERO" << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        if (CompletionCode == JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ACTIVE_PROCESS_ZERO)
            break;
    }
    std::cout << "All done" << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

[image]